# Add horizontal scroll bar when screen size is less than 768px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap for responsive design. But I want to use it for minimum 768px (col-sm-*) width.

I have a bunch of elements with .col-* classes, the problem is that when I resize the window to less than 768px, the whole design breaks down.

How to limit the website's width 768px, and show horizontal scrollbar on smaller window sizes?

For example, I use this dummy method, but of course, it doesn't help:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 768px) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will display a scrollbar, if width parameter is true.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 991px) {
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: doesn't help. I have a bunch of elements with .col-* classes, the problem is that when I resize the window to less than 768px, the whole design breaks down.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the scrollbar try to add this in your css
    @media screen and (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 991px) {
      overflow-x : scroll;
    }